# gcloud auth activate-service-account [ERROR] Please ensure provided key file is valid

Tags: json, service-accounts

I've spent already several hours with this problem but it seems that I can't activate a service account to develop locally an App Engine project (If I deploy teh project it authenticates well since the credentials are injected as an env variable).

**The problem**

1. I created a new service account under IAM on the GC Platform.

    The service account is created correctly I can see it through the console and the
2. Under service account I generated a new JSON key -> key.json
3. in the console I used
   gcloud auth activate-service-account --key file=key.json

### Code

```
 {    
      "type": "service_account",
    <br>      "project_id": "[project id]",
    <br>      "private_key_id": "[private_key_id]",
    <br>      "private_key": "[private_key]",
    <br>      "client_email": "[name]",
    <br>      "client_id": "[clien id]",
    <br>      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    <br>      "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    <br>      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        <br>  "client_x509_cert_url": 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/[client_email]"
       <br> }
```

I receive the error message **ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid.**

---

After trying everything what I could I found that in the docs the service account key indeed has a different structure. https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys
I have no idea however why the downloaded key structure is not good.

Did anybody encounter this issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Also I found another documentation https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: One of the problem I ran into is related to the date/time settings on the machine.  Using NTP solved the issue.

Comment: I tried to set the local time using NTP but it was not working unfortunately. However after some days when I tried it again miraculously it fixed itself... Still don't know and what it fixed it. The NTP however definitely was a step ahead because I observed that the timezone was not correctly set previously...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't found any great documentation on this, but you definitely want the first type of file and creating it through the Cloud Console should work. I believe it's referenced to as a Google Credentials file. The downloaded JSON file should look something like:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id",
  "private_key_id": "some_number",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....
  =\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "<api-name>api@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/...<api-name>api%40project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

The [second link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys) you posted will also create a service account key and a Google Credentials file, but it's probably more work than you want (the Google Credentials file is encoded under the `privateKeyData` field.

Hopefully that explains the files; good luck authenticating! My only suggestion for that is that maybe you've spelled the command wrong?
It should be:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
```

whereas you've typed

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key file=key.json
```

ie, with a space after --key. Let us know if you figure it out!

Comment: After a weekend of resting miraculously everything started to work as is should be according to the documentation. Since then I was using many other service accounts without any problem. I still don't know what was the problem, but I mark this answer to be correct since the advises given here were correct and indeed this typo can be a problem. Who knows I was tired and I forgot a dash :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get token! A new browser window is being opened. Login/Select a Google account, accept the permissions and paste the authentication code below.
```

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=TOKEN

```
The developer hasn't given you access to this app. It's currently being tested and it hasn't been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer
```

https://github.com/Melvin-Abraham/Google-Assistant-Unofficial-Desktop-Client/issues/678#issuecomment-1119102459

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).