# ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) The .json key file is not in a valid format -- via impersonate-service-account

Tags: bash, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud

#### Is it possible to use *short-lived credentials*, with docker-compose, to run a bash scripted gcloud command?

Related posts that I attempted to use but they are 5+ years old and I've been led to believe that the `gcloud auth` command has changed during this time:

- [ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020870/error-gcloud-auth-activate-service-account-failed-to-activate-the-given-servi)
- [gcloud auth activate-service-account [ERROR] Please ensure provided key file is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278622/gcloud-auth-activate-service-account-error-please-ensure-provided-key-file-is)

### Setup

- there is a lot going on but I've attempted to abbreviate to the relevant parts

`Makefile`

```makefile
auth: ## commands for short lived auth
    @gcloud config set project ${GCP_PROJECT}
    @gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account="inst-dataflow-svc@${GCP_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    @gcloud auth configure-docker $(REGION)-docker.pkg.dev

gcloud-flex-build: ## build & push base docker image
    docker-compose build gcloud-build-flex-local
    docker-compose run gcloud-build-flex-local
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  gcloud-build-flex-local:
    build:
      dockerfile: docker/gcloud-build-flex-template.dockerfile
      context: .
    image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/gcp-project/dataflow-docker-registry/local-build/pubsub-to-gbq-build-flex-template
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${HOME}/.config/gcloud/
        target: /tmp
```

`docker/gcloud-build-flex-template.dockerfile`

```dockerfile
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:408.0.1

COPY docker/scripts/gcloud-build-flex-template.sh /app/gcloud-build-flex-template.sh
COPY dataflow/pubsub-to-gbq/pubsub-to-gbq-metadata /app/pubsub-to-gbq-metadata

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT "/app/gcloud-build-flex-template.sh"
```

`/app/gcloud-build-flex-template.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=inst-dataflow-svc@gcp-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
GCP_PROJECT=gcp-project

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/application_default_credentials.json

# debugging
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
ls -lah /tmp/
cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

gcloud auth activate-service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --project=$GCP_PROJECT --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

### Execution

```bash
make auth
make gcloud-flex-build
```

### Error

> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) The .json key file is not in a valid format.

> make: *** [gcloud-flex-build] Error 1

*stdout (abbreviated)*

```
docker-compose build gcloud-build-flex-local
[+] Building 0.4s (9/9) FINISHED
...
docker-compose run gcloud-build-flex-local

drwxr-xr-x 17 root root  544 Dec 30 10:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Dec 30 10:40 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  591 Dec 30 10:36 application_default_credentials.json

{
  "delegates": [],
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/inst-dataflow-svc@gcp-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "source_credentials": {
    "client_id": "alphanumeric string .apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "alphanumeric string",
    "refresh_token": "alphanumeric string",
    "type": "authorized_user"
  },
  "type": "impersonated_service_account"
}
```

I can make it work via `docker run` by spoofing the credentials to include only the "source_credentials" object, passed in as a volume, but this same trick doesn't seem to work with docker-compose running a script inside a container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar type of configuration mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-local-dev-docker-compose). This involves three major steps:

- Create [short-lived credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct) for your service account and download
  your service account keys.
- Create the configuration files for making your docker environment up. Use
  the above cred files for granting required permissions.
- Once you have all the configuration files in place use your docker-compose
  commands for making your environment up.

Follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-local-dev-docker-compose) for more details.

Comment: thank you for the response -- I'll run through the tutorial and accept the answer if this method works for me